# VueJS Single File Component updating data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm really confused with how data works in single file components for VueJS.  Within the file, say test.vue, as I understand, you would write out a script something like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'Testapp',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'sample message'
    }
  }
}
```

then elsewhere, say in a file called vuescript.js I would put something like following in and call it from an html file:

import Vue from 'vue'
import VApp from './test.vue'

```
var vueApp = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: h => h(VApp)
})
```

Now how do I access that template object's data?  What I'd like is to have code elsewhere that fetches data from a server and can be shared across multiple components, so I'd have a portion of data that is common across and updates from a single repository, but also I'd be able to have unshared data residing within a component for certain things like settings and other meta data.

BLUF: I'm kind of stuck after looking around a bit on how data is accessed / is handled within Vue single file components.

Comment: What you're describing is a `store` that holds the data and can be referenced throughout your application. Have no fear [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/intro.html) is here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data inside components should only be accessed outside of themselves in 2 ways. Either an event propagated the data upwards to a parent which can then decide if it needs to be passed to another component as a prop. Or it is stored in Vuex and accessed through getters and mutations.

#### Links

[Component Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props)

[Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Custom-Events)

[Vuex Example](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/tree/dev/examples/shopping-cart)

Answer (score 1):

If you want your data property to be shared by multiple components, you can use mixins.

Mixins are a flexible way to distribute reusable functionalities for Vue components. A mixin object can contain any component options. When a component uses a mixin, all options in the mixin will be “mixed” into the component’s own options.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html